# Предлог за (в) + творительный падеж

Tags: пунктуация

> За обмозговыванием этих вопросов(,) я едва заметил, как в один прекрасный день со стороны коридора послышался подозрительный шум.

Так же «за чтением», «за разглядыванием», «в пении», «в созерцании» и т.д. 
В начале предложения надо отделять запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном предложении запятую лучше не ставить.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Вопрос о постановке запятой в таких случаях решается для конкретного предложения с учетом его структуры. К обособлению склоняет причинный характер обстоятельства, а препятствует обособлению его нераспространенность в составе сложного предложения.

Поэтому актуализацию обстоятельства делать не стоит, да и структура предложения этому не способствует. При его чтении речевой отрезок  "за обмозговыванием этих вопросов (пз) я едва замЕтил" явно составляет одну фразу, а небольшая пауза, которая провоцирует постановку знака препинания, носит только произносительный характер.

Для обособления обстоятельство надо распространить или заменить оборотом:

Ввиду занятости решением этих вопросов,  я едва заметил, как в один прекрасный день со стороны коридора послышался подозрительный шум.

Занятый решением этих вопросов,  я едва заметил, как в один прекрасный день со стороны коридора послышался подозрительный шум.

Answer (score 0):

> > За обмозговыванием этих вопросов...

Оставим это жуткое "обмозговывание"... И зачем оно нужно... Ну ладно, фиг с ним. Итак, вы обмозговываете вопросы.

> > я едва заметил, как в один прекрасный день...

Выходит, вы обмозговывали долгие-долгие дни? Или даже месяцы...
Может, лучше не "в один прекрасный день", а "в одну прекрасную минуту"?

А вообще – претенциозность никогда до хорошего не доводит. Зачем? Будьте проще!

Comment: Приму к сведению.